# how to split vim screen into two parts?

Tags: vim

I want to split Vim screen to two equal parts with line numbers enabled (:nu) editing the same file. I want Vim to take me to the second part of the screen when my first part is filled with code instead of scrolling down.
I want it to keep scrolling in the 2nd part when it's filled and the old Lines will show up in the first screen..

Any help?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, also what should vim do after the 2nd window is full?  (You can split the screen with `:vs`)

Comment: @ElmarPeise when the 2nd window is full, I want it to keep scrolling there and put the old Lines in the first part.

Comment: Use the scripts section of www.vim.org for searching plugins: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545

Comment: @romainl , Installed, works perfectly. Thanks. Not exactly what I'm looking for but It's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [mpage plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545). Better get the latest version directly off [DrChip's homepage](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#MPAGE).